# Adwords without API Key

Tags: google-ads-api

Firstly I know you can get an API key, they rejected my application due to not spending enough with them in the past.

What would be the best way to login each day and grab a report? The days stats.

Im thinking Ruby using Selenium Web Browser Automation with some jitter of the time that grabs the report as they would be quite smart about detecting bots etc

Has anyone done this and is there a better way other than getting an API key?

Comment: Can anyone suggest a better place to seek an answer to my question or a better way to ask it on here then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can schedule reports from the AdWords user interface without messing about in the API at all - see this link for instructions:

https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2404176?hl=en

It's easy enough to set up & they will email you a link to your report each day.

If you need to automate some processing of the report then you could maybe set up a specific email account with reporting access then rig something up to follow the link in the email each day? Probably just as easy as going through the API approval & authorisation process and surely MUCH easier than trying to create some sort of bot to interact with the browser interface in some way!

Comment: Thanks a very constructive answer, it would not be hard to grab the report from the email and parse the data. with the API key, I will continue to try and get one, they rejected me for not doing spending enough/using adwords enough. There is a better way than automating a browser to login!